# How to create dependent dynamic dropdownlist?

Tags: php, ajax

How can I create a dependent dynamic dropdownlist in php. All of the dropdownlist contents / data's will come from the database (I have no problem populating the dropdownlist with the database content)

i.e
**dropdownlist 1**
**dropdownlist 2**

If I select "fruits" on the **dropdownlist 1** it will display items on **dropdownlist 2** such apple, orange, grape.

Second question:

Is there any counter part of the asp.net updatepanel here in php?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Dynamic Drop Down List for PHP](http://www.google.com/search?q=dynamic+dropdown+list+php)